# Create a select query with operations for each index

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access table with a column, let's call that category, that can have 3 possible values (in my case: 0, 1, 2 and 3) and a second column with some number. I need a query that takes the sum of each value in the number column with the same category and return a table with two columns: an indexed category, and a sum value for that index

The workaround I did was to create four queries, one for each category and use four tables with one row each

```
SELECT Sum(Value) FROM myTable WHERE Category = @cat
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT categoryColumn, SUM(valueColumn) FROM table GROUP BY categoryColumn`.

Comment: Simply an aggregate query. Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calc in textbox. Report allows display of detail data as well as summary info.

Answer (score 0):

The following should return the results you require:

```
select t.category, sum(t.value) as categorytotal
from mytable t
group by t.category
```

The above will sum the values held by the `value` field within each group of records which share the same `category` value.

---

If, however, you want the results to appear in a *separate* indexed table, as indicated by your statement:

> I need a query that takes the sum of each value in the number column with the same category and **return a table** with two columns: an indexed category, and a sum value for that index.

Then you could use a [`select into`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) statement:

```
select t.category, sum(t.value) as categorytotal
into categorytotals
from mytable t
group by t.category
```

Followed by a [`create index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-index-statement-microsoft-access-sql) statement to index the `category` field:

```
create index idx_category on categorytotals (category) with primary
```